# How to prevent closing a dialog created by showModalDialog()?

Tags: javascript, html, showmodaldialog

In normal cases, it is possible to handle the `unbeforeunload` event to present a message to the user which gives him the final choice wheter to close or not, as shown here:

```
<script>
    function closeIt() {
        return "Any string value here forces a dialog box to appear before closing the window.";
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = closeIt;
</script>
```

But [this](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/onbeforeunload.htm) seems not to work in markup that is shown by `window.showModalDialog`.
**Update:** *That means if this script is used in the HTML-Code which is displayed by the dialog to prevent the dialog beeing closed accidentially.*
No message appears and the window closes if the "X" is clicked.

I managed to show a dialog using the `<body onunload="return confirm('Really?')"` thing, but in either way the window closes.

I was testing on Internet Explorer 9.

Any ideas?

Comment: @your `window.onbeforeunload = closeIt`; seems to work for me on IE6

Comment: You mean you want to prevent the modal dialog from closing? Or something else?